# want to create that Landing Page

Tags: html, css

[image]

Hi Guys,

I'm trying to build that landing page and I'm stuck I don't know how to divide the page with the two line. one Horizontal line and one vertical line can someone show me the way. please see the attachment.

thanks Guys

Comment: Use [CSS Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout).

Comment: Please visit help center, take tour to see what and How to Ask. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a minimal reproducible example of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a Stacksnippe

Comment: thanks, but I put the design in the attachment. my landing page is divided with two lines. thanks again

Answer (score 1):

use the CSS grid i think it may help even if you didn't explain about your question

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style>
    div{
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(2,1fr);
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
   <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

this will look like this when you point the cursor on the div in the console element
[image]

Comment: Thanks Bro, did you see the picture. I have separate my landing page with 2 . one for the navigation and a second with the social media button. that is what I want to achieve. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Create two seperate div's and give one of them certain width and the other certain height, or you can even use the margin-top and margin-right keyword

And post your code if you have written any